# Cache more tabs to preserve the content when there's no internet connection in Firefox for Android

Tags: firefox-for-android

I've installed Firefox on my Android smartphone. I want to store many opened tabs, but Firefox stores a little number of tabs.

Looks like Firefox only stores a few tabs (about 5 of 25 total), so when I navigate to another tab, Firefox will use the internet connection to load it again. Thus, when there's no internet connection, I will get a connection error page instead. (btw, Opera Mini easily stores about 50 tabs opened)

I've tried to work with `about:config` settings like `browser.cache.disk.capacity` and `browser.cache.check_doc_frequency` but with no success.

I think the problem is with `browser.cache.disk.capacity`, but:

- it's difficult to click too many times (current value is 30720, but I need 100000)
- the browser sets `browser.cache.disk.capacity` back to the default value after some time

What do I need to do to avoid annoying reloads of the page?

Answer (score 0):

According to [a blog article by Geoff Brown, the developer of Firefox for Android](https://gbrownmozilla.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/firefox-for-androids-disk-cache/), looks like you need to disable "smart sizing" feature in Firefox because it sets the cache size dynamically.

I'm now using version 37 and I still don't see any progress in functionality though.